# Twitter framework for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I am trying to develop a Twitter based iPhone application which needs to send some Twitter messages and save those messages locally. But TWTweetComposeViewController in ios5 does not have the facility to save messages typed before clicking the send button. So I am thinking to use some third party frameworks for twitter integration.Please suggest me some good frameworks compatible with lower and latest ios versions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use share kit sdk which will solve your problem i think ,
here is the link go through with this

http://getsharekit.com/install/